# How do you set up a 1.14.4 Minecraft Mod in the java IDE Eclipse?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have set up a minecraft mod in eclipse before, only it was in 1.12.2. I installed the ´src´ forge for 1.12.2, but there is no src option for 1.14.4. I have heard that the code for minecraft was changed, so modding minecraft in 1.14.4 is different to modding 1.12.2 minecraft. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Do you mean the ModCoderPack? 
https://gist.github.com/Pokechu22/97bf5bd528eeadef09dcbae8a15b009f

Comment: @Jonas Considering "I installed the ´src´ forge for 1.12.2" no. They're trying to set up a Forge workspace.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go here: https://files.minecraftforge.net/
2. Click this:
   [image: MDK download button]
   You may alternatively download the recommended build. Forge for 1.14 is still under active development and some features may not be present in the recommended build.
3. Create a folder where you would like your workspace to live, eg `workspace` (I name it with the Forge version number, personally). Inside it create another folder, I name it `project`, but the name isn't important, just that having this extra layer will make things play nice (I will use these names in this answer only to make it clear which folder I'm talking about).
4. Extract the downloaded zip into the `project` folder
5. Shift-right click on the `project` folder and "open power shell here."
6. Run the two commands listed in the readme: `./gradlew genEclipseRuns` and `./gradlew eclipse` (note: do not do steps 4 and 5 of the readme, they are outdated)
7. Open eclipse, switch workspace (File -> Switch Workspace -> Other) to the `workspace` folder. Eclipse will restart.
8. File -> Import...
9. General -> Existing projects into workspace
10. Where it says "select root directory" point it at the `project` folder and check "search for nested projects"
11. Pretty much hit next until its done (or you can hit Finish right away).

This should leave you with a Package Explorer that looks like this:
[image: Package explorer results]

Your code and assets will go inside src/main/java and src/main/resources (note that assets will contain both "assets" and "data" folders, for client-side assets and datapack assets respectively). Minecraft read-only source is available in the Project and External Dependencies group, note that many of the vanilla assets (including data packs) are found in the `client-extra.jar` file.

Lastly:

12. Find the src/main/resources/META-INF/mods.toml file
13. Edit as necessary with your mod ID and other information. The file is well commented.

Any further issues should be directed to the [Modder Support](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/forum/70-modder-support/) forum.